Are temporal coherence (for classical EM waves) and quantum coherence related concepts?
For my wave optics class, I was taught that the temporal coherence of a light source is the average time interval for which the phase of that light is predictable, after which the source will undergo a random phase shift.
I have also heard of the concept of quantum coherence. And as I understand it, a quantum system loses quantum coherence when its wave function collapses (e.g. when measured).
Are these two concepts linked? Are the random phase shifts experienced by light sources a result of quantum decoherence perhaps?

a "coherent state" in quantum mechanics describes a state which has a time evolution closely analogous to the classical case. At least for spatial coherence, these concepts are indeed closely linked, and I see no reason why they would not be for temporal coherence.

Let's say you have a laser at 1000nm .... and like any laser it is not perfect .... every 10th photon comes out at 1001nm (a laser actually puts out a gaussian distribution of frequencies).  The measure of temporal coherence is determined with a spectrometer that measures coherence length. In our example if we interfere the original signal with the same signal delayed by 1um (after 1001 cycles of the main beam and 999 cycles of the other we will get the minimum) at longer delay lengths the signal will build again.  So we say the laser has a coherence length of 1um ... this is the measure of its temporal coherence.
In QM the decoherence term is quite broadly used for photons but in general wave function collapse is not so related. In the DSE the more coherent the light source the sharper the pattern ... yes photon theoretical wave functions are collapsing upon photon absorption.
